# Python Encoding String Issue: String "Île-de-France" is being written to CSV file as "√éle-de-France"

Tags: encoding, utf-8, python-3.6, export-to-csv

I'm trying to write a string "Île-de-France" to a CSV file, however, what is being written to file is "√éle-de-France".  I tried **encoding="utf-8"** in the open and it didn't work.  What am I missing?   Thanks!

```
with open('/tmp/directwrite.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    fieldnames = ['location']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)

    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerow({'location': 'Île-de-France'})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s an issue with your viewer. If using Excel or some other windows program, use`encoding='utf-8-sig'`. That writes a signature at the beginning of the file that Windows programs recognize as a UTF-8 file; otherwise, it assumes an ANSI encoding for the file.